# Mounting custom addons odoo docker v.12

Tags: docker, docker-container, odoo-12

I'm new to this and I do not know if I'm doing the right steps. The first thing I did was create a folder / addons, then inside this folder I created another folder / addons / celes_app, and within this last folder I have all my files (init.py, manifest.py, etc).
Then I create the following containers:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name db postgres:10

docker run -v /addons:/mnt/extra-addons -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo
```

By doing so, the container is successfully created. I open a browser and enter port 8069, it asks me to create a new database, and when I create it I get the following error:

```
2018-11-28 23:45:46,936 1 INFO None odoo.service.db: Create database Prueba. 
2018-11-28 23:45:47,402 1 ERROR None odoo.service.db: CREATE DATABASE 
failed: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3/dist- 
packages/odoo/service/db.py", line 58, in _initialize_db odoo.modules.db.initialize(cr) 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/db.py", line 34, in initialize for i in odoo.modules.get_modules(): 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/module.py", line 408, in get_modules plist.extend(listdir(ad)) 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/module.py", line 401, in listdir for it in os.listdir(dir) 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/extra-addons' 2018-11-28 23:45:47,
422 1 ERROR None odoo.modules.loading: Database Prueba not initialized, you can force it with -i base 2018-11-28 23:45:47,
485 1 INFO Prueba odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'dbname=Prueba user=odoo password=xxxx host=172.17.0.2 port=5432 sslmode=prefer'
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you set the permissions and ownership of that folder in the Dockerfile itself?  The odoo user needs read permission there. That is missing. It needs to be set a build time, in the image.

Comment: Hello Rodrigo, thanks for your answer. I do not understand what permissions you refer to during build time. How do I do that?

Comment: Post your Dockerfile for review. That is where the problem /solution will be.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps & I hope this solution works for you-

> Firstly mount your local folder which contains my extra-addons by the command-

```
$ docker run -v /path/to/your/local/folder:/mnt/extra-addons -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo
```

**Then check weather your local folder is mounted on the Odoo container or not by-**

```
$ docker exec -u root -it odoo /bin/bash
```

**Now you are logged in, (after logging)**

```
$ cd /mnt/extra-addons
$ ls
```

**You should see your files which were present in your local/folder. Now, its done just restart your docker odoo server**

> To stop-

```
$ sudo docker stop db
$ sudo docker stop odoo
$ sudo service docker stop
```

> To Start-

```
$ sudo service docker start
$ sudo docker start db
$ sudo docker start -a odoo
```

**Now you can install your modules from the app and the database should also work fine.**

Comment: Hi Ujjwal, thank you very much for your response. I did what you mention but I have permission problems. When I put "ls -alrt" it gave me the following error: "ls: can not open directory '.': Permission denied".
When I check the properties of the folder I get "drwxr-xr-x. 3 989 root 23 Nov 28 20:57 extra-addons", that is, the owner is "989" (which I do not know what it means) and therefore not I have privileges on her.
I tried to change the owner with "chown -R odoo extra-addons /" but I got the same permission error "chown: can not read directory 'extra-addons /': Permission denied".

Comment: This happens only when creating the docker I place
"-v / addons: / mnt / extra-addons", when I do not place it the owner of the folder is "odoo". To do a test, without placing the code "-v / addons: / mnt / extra-addons" when creating the docker (so that the user
be odoo), create manually within the folder / mnt / extra-addons / my_app a file __init__ and a file __manifest__, and it worked well, odoo was installed and recognized the app and could be installed. Therefore the problem
What I have is permission.

Comment: Why should the owner of the folder be changed to "989" when I place the code "-v / addons: / mnt / extra-addons"? I tried placing the code "-u root -v / addons: / mnt / extra-addons" but the result was the same.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, it seems the permission of extra-addons is ruining everything.
make sure before mounting your extra-addons change it to full permission by `sudo chmod 777 -R /mnt/extra-addons`. And when the permission is changed then you try to mount it as the same file permission is being mounted over the docker container.
Hope this helps!